# Is there a way to specify extra headers while fetching images using Universal Image Loader?

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to user the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info) library to load my images. I trying to call a webservice api to fetch images off it, but it requires the client to attach extra http headers. i.e.:
Access-Token: 124124141241421

Is there a way to dynamically do this in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement your own **ImageDownloader** (extend [ImageDownloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/UniversalImageLoader/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/download/ImageDownloader.java) class and override `InputStream getStreamFromNetwork(URI imageUri)` method) and set it to configuration.
Look into [URLConnectionImageDownloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/UniversalImageLoader/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/download/URLConnectionImageDownloader.java) which is used by default, for example.

You should do like this:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUri.toURL().openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Access-Token", "124124141241421");
```

Comment: Thanks @NOSTRA, got it to work. Will work on some other kink in configuration. Cheers :)