# Sending HTTP Request to get photo in cardslib

Tags: android, cardslib

I'm trying to get photos from secure domain.
In order to be able to get the photo, I've to send HTTP request - or send Cookie - to get the photo.

This code is not working, as it sends normal request.

```
CardThumbnail thumb = new CardThumbnail(getActivity());
String photoUrl = "https://secure.website/image.png";
thumb.setUrlResource(photoUrl);
```

What I need is getting this secure photo by sending the required cookie.

In retrofit, I used to use:

```
request.addHeader("Cookie", "SESSION=123; CSRF_TOKEN=" + token);
```

But what is the solution in cardslib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the built-in function doesn't work.

However you can use **Picasso** to obtain it.For example something like this:

```
 MyThumbnail thumbnail = new MyThumbnail(mContext);
 //You need to set true to use an external library
 thumbnail.setExternalUsage(true);
 addCardThumbnail(thumbnail);


 public class MyThumbnail extends CardThumbnail {

    @Override
    public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View viewImage) {

        //Here you have to set your image with an external library
        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(getContext());
        builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(ctx) {
             @Override
               protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Uri uri) throws IOException {
                  HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(uri);

                  //Put your header values here 
                  connection.setRequestProperty("X-HEADER", "VAL");

                  return connection;
             }
        });          
        Picasso sPicasso = builder.build();
        sPicasso.load("https://secure.website/image.png")
               .into((ImageView)viewImage);

    }

 }
```

If you would like to use the UniversalImageLoader library, you can integrate the library in a similar way, as described here:

https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/OTHERLIBRARIES.md#using-card-with-android-universal-image-loader

To add parameters to the header in UIL, you can refer this question on SO:

[Is there a way to specify extra headers while fetching images using Universal Image Loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253995/is-there-a-way-to-specify-extra-headers-while-fetching-images-using-universal-im)

Comment: Thanks. But I need to used UniversalImageLoader instead of Picasso. Do you have solution for UIL?

Comment: @ArabAgile You can integrate UIL in the same way. I've just edited the answer. Hovewer I don't know well this library about the possibility to add headers to http requests. I reported a link in SO for this feature.